# carouFredSel in fancy box popup

Tags: jquery, fancybox, carousel

am designing a website for shopping cart. And when user clicks quick view the pop-up should open with the details of the products , this includes magnify of image and carouFredSel gallery. But my problem is the carouFredSel is not working in fancybox pop up.
Link : [Link for page](http://pacificit.in/snap/1/productview.php)
Click on zoom image of first product, the popup will display.

This is what i want in pop-up [Link](http://pacificit.in/snap/1/productdescription.php)

Comment: Please answer any one

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem: The slider inside the fancybox is hidden first (display: none), so the carousel doesn't know how to set the width and height. The links to your pages don't load here, so I can't see the exact details. Does the carousel load when you resize the browser? (When the popup is visible.)

You might want to test it with the width and height of the carousel set to a specific width and height.

```
$('#your-slider').carouFredSel({
    responsive: true,
    width: '100%', // Or set to e.g. 600
    height: 'variable', // Or set to e.g. 400
    items: {
        width: 600,
        height: 400
    }
}
});
```